# Не корректно работает сборщик gulp

Tags: gulp

Собираю проекты при помощи gulp.Сборщик в целом работает нормально, но есть коллизия - если в файл pug включать include и подключать какие-то сторонние файлы модулями, то он перестает собирать, выдает кучу ошибок. Кто может подсказать где и в чем ошибка?Вот файл gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    // jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;


var path = {
    build: { 
        html: 'build/',
        js: 'build/js/',
        css: 'build/css/',
        img: 'build/img/',
        fonts: 'build/fonts/'
    },
    src: { 
        html: 'src/index.pug', 
        js: 'src/js/main.js',
        style: 'src/style/common.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: { 
        html: 'src/**/*.pug',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: "./build"
    },
    tunnel: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    logPrefix: "Deep_web"
};

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)) 
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js) 
        .pipe(rigger()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            // indentedSyntax: true,
            // errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 4 versions'],
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img) 
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img)) 
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch(path.watch.fonts, function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Вот что выводит в ошибку

```
{ Error: the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\src\index.pug line 10
    at Function.resolve (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:62:11)
    at Object.resolve (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:136:19)
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:22:26
    at walkAST (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:23:18)
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:103:18)
    at walkAST (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:37:19)
    at walkAST (D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:48:21)
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\svg\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
  name: 'Error',
  message: 'the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths\n    at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\src\\index.pug line 10',
  stack: 'Error: the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths\n
   at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\src\\index.pug line 10\n    at Function.resolve (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-load\\index.js:62:11)\n    at Object.resolve (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug\\lib\\index.js:136:19)\n    at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-load\\index.js:22:26\n
  at walkAST (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:23:18)\n    at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:104:20\n    at Array.reduce (native)\n    at walkAndMergeNodes (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:103:18)\n    at walkAST (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:37:19)\n    at walkAST (D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:48:21)\n    at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\svg\\node_modules\\pug-walk\\index.js:104:20',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-pug' }
```

Comment: напишите цитатой что именно пишет при ошибках..

Comment: Дополнил вопрос с приведение лога ошибки